# is it possible to run this script faster?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to repeatably run this script in **Chrome Developer Console** faster? I want to run the script as fast as possible, right now it repeats itself too slowly...

***AND no it's not because of the api response time... I've seen people call this api extremely fast... And of course they won't reveal to me how they did it.***

Here's the code:

```
ran = -1
function buy(){
  ran++;
  var id = 24826853;
  var price = 190;
  $.get('https://www.roblox.com/catalog/' + id, function(data){
    var html = $(data);
    var bestprice = $('#item-container', html).attr('data-expected-price');
    console.log('Checking for a good price... Current price: ' + bestprice + ' | Times the script has ran: ' + ran);
    var sellerid = $('#item-container', html).attr('data-expected-seller-id');
    var productid = $('#item-container', html).attr('data-product-id');
    var userasset = $('#item-container', html).attr('data-lowest-private-sale-userasset-id');

    if(bestprice <= price){
      // execute purchase
      console.log('Item Found For ' + bestprice);
    }
  }).promise().done(buy);
}

buy();
```

**Here's an example on how fast the code is running**:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3fvN.gif

Maybe you guys could fiddle with my script to make it run faster?

(And yes this is a repost of my question, but slightly edited. I reposted this to get more attention to my question)

Comment: Calling `$('#item-container', html)` four times is definitely a code smell, but probably not the cause of the slowness.

Comment: No, `$` and `.attr` really are pretty slow. But really, what are you optimizing for?

Comment: why are you running it in the chrome dev console? why not run it as a node script?

Comment: Is there a reason you need to repeatedly fetch the entire HTML of  `https://www.roblox.com/catalog/` if you're just using the same hard-coded parameter each time? Or are you changing the ID?

Comment: @JessPatton how would I do so? (By the way I do not own the website)

Comment: @TylerRoper Seems like OP is trying to camp the site to purchase some item when its price drops below some threshold.

Comment: @TylerRoper I need to repeatedly fetch the html to constantly get the price of the item.

Comment: @Saniyah Don't tell people to run your code that would execute a purchase if the item's price dropped below $190 (!). Yeesh. I've edited that suggestion out of your question, along with the dangerous code.

Comment: Judging by how you're actually purchasing the item *(which has since been redacted)*, Roblox obviously exposes a public API. Why not use it to fetch the price for an item, instead of loading the entirety of the page's HTML? [Roblox Web APIs](http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php/Web_APIs) - scroll down to *"Get information about an asset"*.

Comment: @JLRishe yeah, but I'm sure many people here don't play the game Roblox and it's not common for the item I gave to go to 190 or under 190.

Comment: @Saniyah That's not an excuse for asking people to run potentially harmful code.

Comment: @TylerRoper the problem with that is I can't get `data-expected-seller-id` from that api.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't call `buy()` recursivly *after* the previous one has finished, rather just call it in a regular loop like

```
while(true){
  buy();
}
```

instead of the single call at the end of your code.

If this is too fast for you, use an Interval for calling `buy()`. Just put this line where you want to call it:

```
setInterval(buy,1000);
```

1000 is the time between calls in milliseconds so you can change it to whatever you like.

Comment: the `while(true){ buy(); }` crashed the tab I ran the script on

Comment: Both of them will use every resource they can get to perform as many requests as possible so you can't interact with it anymore. The "crashing" shows that it's working but if you want to limit the call rate you can use `setInterval(buy,1000)` to call `buy()` every second.